# How to draw straight lines to indicate repeat values in merged table cells?

Tags: tables, formatting

Can you help me the following working: I'm looking to indicate that the value 2.00 is repetitive vertically through a straight line like in this sketch (the result should be a solid, continuous line, not discontinuous like in the pic). I'm working in the tabular environment.

[image: What i have in mind]

Comment: could you add a MWE of that table? It saves people time when answering you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick Tikz answer:

I created two new commands called `\upbar` and `\downbar` that connect to each other so that the spacing to the top of the table, the text, and the bottom of the table remains correct. If the bars were to connect to the top and bottoms of the table, it would look like a vertical rule, which isn't what you want.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\upbar}{\tikz[overlay] \draw (0,1em)--(0,0em);}
\newcommand{\downbar}{\tikz[overlay] \draw (0,.5em)--(0,-1em);}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        \hline
        foo & \downbar  & bar\\
        foo & \downbar  & bar\\
        baz & \upbar    & bat\\
        baz & label     & bat\\
        baz & \downbar  & bat\\
        baz & \downbar  & bat\\
        baz & \downbar  & bat\\
        baz & \upbar    & bat\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular} 

    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        \hline
        A & \downbar & 3.45\\
        B & \upbar & 6.12\\
        C & 2.00 & 7.93\\
        D & \downbar & 0.31\\
        E & \upbar & 9.21\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution you might find helpful, though it throws off the table formatting slightly. Here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        \hline
        A & $\Big|$ & 3.45\\
        B & $\Big|$ & 6.12\\
        C & $2$ & 7.93\\
        D & $\Big|$ & 0.31\\
        E & $\Big|$ & 9.21\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here is a comparison of the two:
[image: Table Comparison]

Essentially I just made the vertical bars "big" to the point where TeX had no choice but to join them. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In English and other , the `ditto mark` is a `double prime`(U+2033), often replaced with a double quote. In French and Swiss German it's a `right guillemot`. You also can use an emdash.  Here is a way of doing in four ways (including what you ask):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\mathversion{bold}}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}[t]{c >{\rule[-0.15ex]{0.4pt}{1.7ex}}c S[table-format = 1.2]}
\toprule
    A & & 3.45 \\
    B & & 6.12\\
    C &\multicolumn{1}{c}{200} & 7.93 \\
    D & & 0.31 \\
     E & & 9.21 \\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\qquad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c >{$''}c<{$}S[table-format = 1.2]}
\toprule
    A & \multicolumn{1}{c}{200} & 3.45 \\
    B & & 6.12\\
    C & & 7.93 \\
    D & & 0.31 \\
     E & & 9.21 \\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\vskip 1cm
 \begin{tabular}{c >{\textemdash}cS[table-format = 1.2]}
\toprule
    A & \multicolumn{1}{c}{200} & 3.45 \\
    B & & 6.12\\
    C & & 7.93 \\
    D & & 0.31 \\
     E & & 9.21 \\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\qquad
 \begin{tabular}{c >{\guillemotright}cS[table-format = 1.2]}
\toprule
    A & \multicolumn{1}{c}{200} & 3.45 \\
    B & & 6.12\\
    C & & 7.93 \\
    D & & 0.31 \\
     E & & 9.21 \\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below I've overlaid the repetition using a `\colorbox` with `white` background. Two example show how things will look with [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and without, as well as with an even/odd number of rows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lc|cl}
  \hline
  A & &&  3.45 \\
  B & &&  6.12 \\
  C & &\llap{\makebox[0pt]{\colorbox{white}{2}}\hspace{\tabcolsep}} & 7.93 \\
  D & &&  0.31 \\
  E & &&  9.21 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular} \qquad
\begin{tabular}{lc|cl}
  \toprule
  A & &&  3.45 \\
  B & &&  6.12 \\
  C & &\llap{\makebox[0pt]{\colorbox{white}{2}}\hspace{\tabcolsep}} & 7.93 \\
  D & &&  0.31 \\
  E & &&  9.21 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lc|cl}
  \hline
  A & &&  3.45 \\
  A & &&  3.45 \\
  B & &&  6.12 \\
  C & &\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\llap{\makebox[0pt]{\colorbox{white}{2}}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}} & 7.93 \\
  D & &&  0.31 \\
  E & &&  9.21 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular} \qquad
\begin{tabular}{lc|cl}
  \toprule
  A & &&  3.45 \\
  A & &&  3.45 \\
  B & &&  6.12 \\
  C & &\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\llap{\makebox[0pt]{\colorbox{white}{2}}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}} & 7.93 \\
  D & &&  0.31 \\
  E & &&  9.21 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Adjustment of `\fboxsep` would increase the background size and therefore also increase the distance of the vertical rule to the `2`.